# How to move an object into uninitialized memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Given an allocated but uninitialized memory location, how do I move some object into that location (destroying the original), **without** constructing potentially expensive intermediate objects?

Comment: by "move" do you mean copy object?

Comment: @MoatazElmasry No, he literally means [move](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/), not copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use placement new to move-construct it in the memory:

```
void * memory = get_some_memory();
Thing * new_thing = new (memory) Thing(std::move(old_thing));
```

If it has a non-trivial destructor, then you'll need to explicitly destroy it when you're done:

```
new_thing->~Thing();
```

Comment: Whoa, I thought a move constructor needs the current object to be valid, so it can swap it with the temporary! Was I wrong?

Comment: Moving and swapping are not the same thing at all. A move constructor *initializes* a new object from an already existing object, whereas swapping requires two existing objects.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Ohhh... yeah.. it's my first time writing a move constructor so I thought I have to swap with the input (so that when it goes out of scope it takes everything with it) instead of just taking ownership.... that makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: Swapping makes perfect sense in the move assignment operator.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Ahh... totally forgot about the move-assignment operator (never actually written one either)! Yeah now the distinction is clear... awesome, thanks!